# JQuery Picture Memory Game

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays

My question is as follows, how could I pass images that are inside an array to a div?

I've multiplied the div#imagem and I need to pass the array images to it.

But I do not know how.. Can someone help me?!

My JavaScript/JQuery

```
var divBoard = $("<div id='board'></div>");
$("body").after(divBoard);
var titleGame = $("<h1></h1>").text("Memory Game");
var btnReset = $("<input id='btn-reset' type='button' onclick='reset()' value='Reset'>");
$("#board").append(titleGame);
$("#board").append(btnReset);

(function (){
var images = ['img/facebook.png','img/android.png','img/chrome.png','img/firefox.png','img/html5.png','img/googleplus.png','img/twitter.png','img/windows.png','img/cross.png'];

  $(window).load(function () {

        $('#board').html('');

        var numCards = 16;

        for (var i = 1; i <= numCards; i++) {

            $("#board").append("<div class='image" + i + " images'></div>") &&
            $(".image" + i).clone().appendTo("#board");

        }
            var cards = $(".images");

        for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
            var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
            var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
            var target3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
        }
})();


app.start();
});
```

My HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <title>JavaScript Memory Game</title>
</head>
<body>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script charset="utf8">
  var app = { nrComponents:0 };
  app.getComponent = function(name) {
    if (!app[name]) {
      app[name] = {};
      app[app.nrComponents++] = name;
    }
    return app[name];
  };
</script>
<script src="script.js" charset="utf8"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `But I can not do this` what does this mean? Do you get errors? If so, what errors?

Comment: For example, when I try to use something like this:
$ (".imagens"). pop (imagens);
"Class div imagens" taking array elements.
What I can not do is pass the elements of the array into the cloned divs created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are critical 2 problems I listed. Some line in your code seems not neccecery and hard to debug for it. I would suggest to simplify your code for better debugging.Hope it helps..

1. $("body").after(divTabuleiro); I think this will insert content after 'body' instead of putting 'divTabuleiro' inside the 'body'.
2. $("#tabuleiro").append(""); should have  tag inside for insert images.

```js
// Create a start function and move you initial code here....
app.start = function(){
  var imagens = [
    'https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/img15/pet-products/small-tiles/23695_pets_vertical_store_dogs_small_tile_8._CB312176604_.jpg',
    'http://www.pressunion.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/11/1-2.jpg',
    'http://www.feixiubook.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/01-25.jpg'
  ];
  
  var divTabuleiro = $("<div id='tabuleiro'></div>");
  $("body").append(divTabuleiro);
  var titulo = $("<h1></h1>").text("Jogo da Memória");
  var btnReset = $("<input id='btn-reset' type='button' onclick='reset()' value='Reset'>");
  $("#tabuleiro").append(titulo);
  $("#tabuleiro").append(btnReset);

  $('#tabuleiro').html('');

  var numCards = 3;

  for (var i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {

    var img = imagens[i];
    $("#tabuleiro").append("<div class='my-image-" + i + " my-image'><img src='" + img + "'></div>") && $(".my-image-" + i).clone().appendTo("#tabuleiro");
  }

  // randomize cards in stack
  var cards = $(".my-image");
  for (var i = 0; i < cards.length; i++) {
    var target = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
    var target2 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
    var target3 = Math.floor(Math.random() * cards.length - 1) + 1;
    cards.eq(target).before(cards.eq(target2)).before(cards.eq(target3));
  }
};

// Maybe create another function
app.reset = function(){

};


$(window).ready(function() {
  // Because you have created a start function above. you can call it when document ready
  app.start();
});
```

```css
.my-image {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: hidden;
  float: left;
}

.my-image img {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
// Create a namespace of app
var app = { nrComponents:0 };
// Add a function 'getComponent' in to it
app.getComponent = function(name) {
  if (!app[name]) {
    app[name] = {};
    app[app.nrComponents++] = name;
  }
  return app[name];
};
// So There is no start() function inside......
// we can add start function later..
</script>
```

Comment: It did not work for me, that app.start () and function:

<script charset="utf8">
  var app = { nrComponents:0 };
  app.getComponent = function(name) {
    if (!app[name]) {
      app[name] = {};
      app[app.nrComponents++] = name;
    }
    return app[name];
  };
</script>

I have to make use of them, but I believe that this is a concept of namespace, except that I am not able to apply in the game of memory. =S

Comment: it isn't working? did you click the button "Run code snippet".

Comment: Now that I've seen, it's working fine. I was applying it the wrong way. 
Could you explain to me how the namespace concept works, for example in my html code I have to use `<script charset="utf8"> var app = { nrComponents:0 }; app.getComponent = function(name) { if (!app[name]) { app[name] = {}; app[app.nrComponents++] = name; } return app[name]; }; </script>` and i need to use the app.start();

Comment: var app = {}; it creates an Object for adding some properties and functions in it. If you have to use app.start() you need to create that function first and move your initial code in it... check the updated snippet above. If it makes you clear. please accept my answer.

Comment: Thank you, you have helped to clear  my doubts. Now I'll try to solve the rest myself. =)

Answer (score 0):

Hm.. I somehow don't understand your exact request, but for making images based on an array you can use this as a guide :

```
var imagens = ['img/facebook.png','img/android.png','img/chrome.png','img/firefox.png','img/html5.png','img/googleplus.png','img/twitter.png','img/windows.png','img/cross.png'];

$.each(imagens,function(index,imageSrc){
      $("Parent Element").append('<img src="'+imageSrc+'" />');
});
```

hope it helps.

Comment: So the code I was based on came from here http://jsfiddle.net/007y4rju/1/

But instead of using click, I want to use load to read the DOM and in
Var numCards = parseInt ($ ('input'). Val ());
I want to pass var numCards = 16;
And the images I want to pass those from within the array.

Sorry for my english.

Comment: Well, Np :) I want to help... 
If you want to remove on-click and instead doing something on load.. just remove the onclick event you created.. as your code is already inside the document ready function it will be called after DOM is ready.
For var numCards = 16 :P can't u just assign 16? I just don't get if you plan other thing.. 
For images I must say based on your jsfiddle I don't know where do u want to render images... in the tiles?

Comment: The 16 is because I want to create a 4x4 board. =)

I'll study some more about javascript and jquery, it's because I'm new to this language.